# Laravel Queue, Connection to tcp://smtp.office365.com:587 Timed Out

Tags: php, laravel, tcp, smtp, office365

I am using `Microsoft outlook SMTP` details for sending emails from my website to other users.

I configured Queue/Jobs functionality to send emails.

**SMTP settings**

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.office365.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=info@abcxyz.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=abcyxz45
MAIL_FROM_NAME=ABC Mailer
MAIL_FROM_EMAIL=info@abcxyz.com
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
```

**dispatching Job Code**

```
$job    =   new SendReportEmail($job_data);
$this->dispatch($job);
```

**mail sending code**

```
class SendReportEmail extends Job implements SelfHandling, ShouldQueue
{
    use InteractsWithQueue, SerializesModels;

    var $data   =   null;

    public function __construct($data)
    {
        $this->data =   $data;
    }

    public function handle()
    {

        $response           =   $this->data['response'];
        $EntrepreneurPdf    =   $response->pdf;

        Mail::send('emailTemplates.imResults', ['response' => $response], function ($message) use ($response, $EntrepreneurPdf)  {

            $message->subject($response->subject);
            $message->to($response->provider_email);

            $this->checkForEntrepreneurReportAttachment($response, $message, $EntrepreneurPdf);

        });
    }
}
```

When I run this command to execute Queued jobs

`php artisan queue:listen --timeout=300`

Process is starts, and sometimes I got below error, so due to error and queued again and again attempts, I got same email multiple times.

> ```
> Processed: Illuminate\Queue\CallQueuedHandler@call
>
>
>   [Swift_TransportException]                            
>   Connection to tcp://smtp.office365.com:587 Timed Out
> ```

What and Where can be the issue?

Comment: Can you send emails using those credentials without queueing the job?

Comment: Yes, I can send email using those credentials. Normal email as will as queuing job. But often I faces connection time out issue while working with queued Jobs.

Answer (score 0):

On your sever try ping the smtp

```
telnet smtp.office365.com 587
```

Answer (score 0):

Currently there are sending limits (30 messages per minute), see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office365/servicedescriptions/exchange-online-service-description/exchange-online-limits?redirectedfrom=MSDN#receiving-and-sending-limits).

You should consider using REDIS throttle, see [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/queues#rate-limiting).